# Is there a way to find the latest date that is more than n days in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, join, case

I'm trying to find which asset has not been borrow for the last 90days.
The logic would be something like

```
IF latest date of an asset returned_date > 90 days
    more than 90 days
ELIF created_date > 90 days
    more than 90 days
ELSE
    not more than 90 days
```

How do I write all of that into a single query

**loan**

```
loan_id   asset_id   returned_date
1         1          2019-12-14 12:00:00.000
2         1          2019-12-10 12:00:00.000
3         2          2020-11-10 12:00:00.000
```

**asset**

```
asset_id   created_date
1          2019-12-05 12:00:00.000
2          2019-12-05 12:00:00.000
3          2019-12-05 12:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help! Really appreciated it. I have found another way of solving this query which is to find the asset that has been borrow in the last 90 day instead. And then minus it off the original asset table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just a `not exists` query.  There are two conditions:

- The asset was created at least 90 days ago.
- There have been no returns in the last 90 days.

This would be:

```
select a.*
from asset a
where a.create_date < dateadd(day, -90, getdate()) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from loan l
                  where l.asset_id = a.asset_id and
                        l.return_date >= dateadd(day, -90, getdate())
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query returns only those assets that have not been borrowed for 90 days.

Notes:

- If an asset has not been borrowed at all, its create date is used in the
  calculation (marked by ** in the code)
- If an asset has been borrowed multiple times, the most recent one is
  used in the calculation (marked by *** in the code)

> ```
> select * from(
>   select
>       a.asset_id,
>       l.loan_id,
>       isnull(l.return_date,a.create_date) as return_date, -- **
>       rank() over(partition by a.asset_id order by l.return_date desc) as rnk -- ***
>   from asset a
>   left join loan l on a.asset_id=l.asset_id
> )x
> where
>   rnk=1 -- ***
>   and datediff(day,return_date, getdate())>=90
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement along with `DATEADD` (here `dd` represents days) to categorize which is borrowed or not (**Solution 1**). Then, if you wish to show one or the other, you would move the conditions to check this to a `WHERE` clause (**Solution 2**).

#### Solution 1

```
select
  t1.asset_id,
  t2.returned_date,
  case when t2.returned_date > dateadd(dd,90,t1.created_date) then 'more than 90 days'
  else 'not more than 90 days'
  end as 'borrow window'
  from asset t1
  join loan t2
  on t2.asset_id = t1.asset_id
```

#### Solution 2

```
select t1.*, t2.returned_date 
from asset t1
join loan t2
on t2.asset_id = t1.asset_id
where t2.returned_date > dateadd(dd, 90, t1.created_date) -- only > 90
```